# When creating a form using PDFBox, when creating PDRadioButton or PDCheckBox, how do you create a label for each instance that toggles input on click?

Tags: java, forms, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have used many PDF forms where if you click on the label for a radio, it "checks" that radio button, if you click the label for a check box, it toggles the "checked" state of that check box. Is there anyway to create these using PDFBox?

```
<!-- I know how to do this in HTML -->
<input type="checkbox" name="example" id="example"/>
<label for="example">
  This is an example of a checkbox whose state
  can be changed by clicking on it's label
</label>
```

Comment: CreateCheckBox.java creates a PDF with one checkbox with no label. Does not exactly show how to trigger state change of checkbox by clicking on it's label. CreateCheckBox.java has no label

Comment: Can you share an example PDF with label clicking? Strictly speaking plain PDF does not support active labels. There might be work-arounds, though. If you show us a PDF with such a working work-around, we can try and help you implementing it with PDFBox. But please make sure that it's not a PDF with an XFA form but with an AcroForm form.

Comment: You are correct, I was mistaken when I remembered having populated a PDF form that allowed activation of a check box or radio button by clicking on the label